# The index not what i expected C# unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I found a problem about the index on my script, why my index on method ChooseItem become 1 not 0?
here the script

```
public void AddBtn()
{
    RemoveButton();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        indexer = i;
        ShopItem activeOne = items[indexer];
        go = Instantiate(prefabBtn, parentBtn);
        btn = go.GetComponent<_button>();
        btn.indexer = indexer;
        btn.TheItems.sprite = items[indexer].theitem;
        btn.button.onClick.AddListener(() =>chooseItem(indexer));
    }
}

public void chooseItem(int index)
{

    Debug.Log(index);
}
```

I don't know the problem, can anyone explain to me why? here the pict [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite typical mistake when using lambdas!

You overwrite a field value

```
indexer = i;
```

Then this line

```
btn.button.onClick.AddListener(() =>chooseItem(indexer));
```

or better said the listener [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)

```
()=>chooseItem(indexer);
```

is executed lazy/delayed using the `indexer` field reference, not the current value! It will always use the latest value of the field `indexer` which in your case is `1` if there are two buttons in total.

This is called [**capture** of outer variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions#capture-of-outer-variables-and-variable-scope-in-lambda-expressions):

> Lambdas can refer to outer variables. These are the variables that are in scope in the method that defines the lambda expression, or in scope in the type that contains the lambda expression. Variables that are captured in this manner are stored for use in the lambda expression even if the variables would otherwise go out of scope and be garbage collected.

*Same would happen btw if you directly used `i`.*

---

What you need to do is assign the value to a local variable and use that one instead like

```
var currentIndex = i;

...

btn.button.onClick.AddListener(() =>chooseItem(currentIndex));
```

Or alternatively if you assign the value anyway to `btn.indexer` you probably could directly go

```
btn.button.onClick.AddListener(() => chooseItem(btn.indexer));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this code:

```
public void AddBtn()
{
    RemoveButton();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        indexer = i;
        ShopItem activeOne = items[indexer];
        go = Instantiate(prefabBtn, parentBtn);
        btn = go.GetComponent<_button>();
        btn.indexer = indexer;
        btn.TheItems.sprite = items[indexer].theitem;
        btn.button.onClick.AddListener(() =>chooseItem(btn));
    }
}

public void chooseItem(_button_ btn)
{

    Debug.Log(btn.indexer);
}
```